# Adding trailing slash to specific URL pattern and redirecting the resulting URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is kind of a complicated one to explain but here we go:

I'm trying to work out getting my escaped fragment URLs to work properly. They do work with a traling / but they don't without. My URLs deafult to ones without a trailing / and my app set up won't allow them so I think the only option is to redirect the initial URL with the exact patter to add the trailing /.

So what I'd like to do is redirect:

http://domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=bike/87/Basso+Loto+105+2013 
to
http://domain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=bike/87/Basso+Loto+105+2013/
and then that gets redirected to:
http://domain.com/bike/87/Basso+Loto+105+2013/

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in one step like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?_escaped_fragment_=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I think that has just solved a problem I was trying to figure out for the past couple of weeks.

Comment: Just one question, it seems to encode the end of the URL, so the + and so on are replaced with %252 is there a way around that? I don't think it matters too much though. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool thanks for that! Facebook still seems to want to 404 on the redirect when I test it with their open graph debug tool. Not sure why and it's still returned the encoded URL.

Comment: I do. For some reason Facebook reads the URL differently and returns it like     http://domain.com/%2Fbike%2F318%2FCannondale%2BSuperSix%2BEVO%2BHi-MOD%2BRED%2C%2BRacing%2BEdition%2B2013%2BRo/ which 404s. You've answered my question though so thanks again.

Comment: I think FB must be caching the URLs.